# Force HTTPS for only a couple URLs?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, https, redirect

I have tried every single thing I've come across to get only 2 specific URLs to redirect to `https`.  NOTHING has worked.  Here's what I have right now in `.htaccess`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} topdeal(.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} watchstore(.*)
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule .? https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule with `THE_REQUEST` variable instead of `REQUEST_FILENAME`:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} watchstore|topdeal [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Comment: This did not work.  The aforementioned URLs went straight to `http`

Comment: Try moving this as first rule. Can you show full .htaccess in question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following in your `.htaccess` file. What the below does is force everything to HTTP except for the directories `watchstore` and `topdeal`. Both are forced to HTTPs.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/(watchstore|topdeal)
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/(watchstore|topdeal)
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Make sure you clear your cache before testing this.

**EDIT:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/(watchstore|topdeal)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/(watchstore|topdeal)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Strange, the first rules were working and tested for me. I've put together an alternative for you to try.